# send hebrew word at java selenium test

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to send keys that include hebrew word,for example:

```
driver.findElement(locator).sendKeys("עלינו")
```

this works well on my local machine,but when I execute my test on jenkins master, hebrew words look as gibberish.
the browser at jenkins slave support hebrew (i checked it manually).
Can anyone suggest a solution.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using Unicode escaped characters:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

If your build machine is Linux, and your development machine Windows, check the source encoding in you build tool.